# Populate one to one relationship's custom field in SugarCRM 6.5

Tags: sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM 6.5 community version and I need to create one edit view with merge related module. See here is scenario:

1. First parent module "Meetings"
2. I have create second module and it's name is "Driver Guide Service"

So the two modules have one-to-one relationship.

I want to render Driver Guide Service's custom field in Meetings's Edit view.

Here is existing relationship. and now I want to create driver_guide_service_cstm'field's  dictionary in Meeting's module that's not working.

```
$dictionary["Meeting"]["fields"]["meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1"] = array (
  'name' => 'meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1',
  'type' => 'link',
  'relationship' => 'meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1',
  'source' => 'non-db',
  'module' => 'dri_driver_guide_service',
  'bean_name' => 'dri_driver_guide_service',
  'vname' => 'LBL_MEETINGS_DRI_DRIVER_GUIDE_SERVICE_1_FROM_DRI_DRIVER_GUIDE_SERVICE_TITLE',
  'id_name' => 'meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1dri_driver_guide_service_idb',
);
$dictionary["Meeting"]["fields"]["meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1_name"] = array (
  'name' => 'meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1_name',
  'type' => 'relate',
  'source' => 'non-db',
  'vname' => 'LBL_MEETINGS_DRI_DRIVER_GUIDE_SERVICE_1_FROM_DRI_DRIVER_GUIDE_SERVICE_TITLE',
  'save' => true,
  'id_name' => 'meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1dri_driver_guide_service_idb',
  'link' => 'meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1',
  'table' => 'dri_driver_guide_service',
  'module' => 'dri_driver_guide_service',
  'rname' => 'name',
);
$dictionary["Meeting"]["fields"]["meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1dri_driver_guide_service_idb"] = array (
  'name' => 'meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1dri_driver_guide_service_idb',
  'type' => 'link',
  'relationship' => 'meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1',
  'source' => 'non-db',
  'reportable' => false,
  'side' => 'left',
  'vname' => 'LBL_MEETINGS_DRI_DRIVER_GUIDE_SERVICE_1_FROM_DRI_DRIVER_GUIDE_SERVICE_TITLE',
);
```

**This below are not working for custom column.**

```
$dictionary["Meeting"]["fields"]["meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1_dri_start_city_c"] = array (
  'name' => 'meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1_dri_start_city_c',
  'type' => 'relate',
  'source' => 'non-db',
  'vname' => 'LBL_MEETINGS_DRI_DRIVER_GUIDE_SERVICE_1_FROM_DRI_DRIVER_GUIDE_SERVICE_TITLE',
  'save' => true,
  'id_name' => 'meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1dri_driver_guide_service_idb',
  'link' => 'meetings_dri_driver_guide_service_1',
  'table' => 'dri_driver_guide_service',
  'module' => 'dri_driver_guide_service',
  'rname' => 'dri_start_city_c',
);
```

this "dri_start_city_c" is custom column for "dri_driver_guide_service"'s module. and this I want to render in meeting module's edit view. all other column are working fine except custom column so anyone can help me to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566179/sugarcrm-creating-relationship-using-module-loader-package-not-installing/45605403#45605403) link to create any type of relationships in custom modules using module loader.

You can either include it in your package or you can upload separately.