# sugarCRM : creating relationship using module loader, package not installing

Tags: php, relationship, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying to create relationships through module loader in SugarCRM. But the problem is my package is stopped installing after 55%. When I am viewing display log the error is:-

> Failed to copy
>   cache/upgrades/temp/SYWr9G/custom/metadata/accounts_contacts_1MetaData.php
>   custom/metadata/accounts_contacts_1MetaData.php

I tried to change permissions also but at some point they through internal server error 500. Following are the code which I am using.

```
1.In manifest.php file :
    $installdefs = array(
        'id' => 'package_20170804',
        'copy' => array(
            0 => array(
                'from' => '<basepath>/accounts_contacts_1MetaData.php',
                'to' => 'custom/metadata/accounts_contacts_1MetaData.php',
                ),
            1 => array(
                'from' => '<basepath>/accounts_contacts_1.php',
                'to' => 'custom/Extension/application/Ext/TableDictionary/accounts_contacts_1.php',
                ),
            ),
        'relationships'=>array (
            array (
                'module'=> 'Accounts',
                'meta_data'=>'<basepath>/custom/metadata/accounts_contacts_1MetaData.php',
               'module_vardefs'=>'<basepath>/custom/Extension/application/Ext/TableDictionary/accounts_contacts_1.php'

                )
            ),
        );

2. In accounts_contacts_1MetaData.php file :

    <?php
    $dictionary["accounts_contacts_1"] = array (
      'true_relationship_type' => 'one-to-many',
      'from_studio' => true,
      'relationships' =>
      array (
        'accounts_contacts_1' =>
        array (
          'lhs_module' => 'Accounts',
          'lhs_table' => 'accounts',
          'lhs_key' => 'id',
          'rhs_module' => 'Contacts',
          'rhs_table' => 'contacts',
          'rhs_key' => 'id',
          'relationship_type' => 'many-to-many',
          'join_table' => 'accounts_contacts_1_c',
          'join_key_lhs' => 'accounts_contacts_1accounts_ida',
          'join_key_rhs' => 'accounts_contacts_1contacts_idb',
          ),
        ),
      'table' => 'accounts_contacts_1_c',
      'fields' =>
      array (
        0 =>
        array (
          'name' => 'id',
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'len' => 36,
          ),
        1 =>
        array (
          'name' => 'date_modified',
          'type' => 'datetime',
          ),
        2 =>
        array (
          'name' => 'deleted',
          'type' => 'bool',
          'len' => '1',
          'default' => '0',
          'required' => true,
          ),
        3 =>
        array (
          'name' => 'accounts_contacts_1accounts_ida',
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'len' => 36,
          ),
        4 =>
        array (
          'name' => 'accounts_contacts_1contacts_idb',
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'len' => 36,
          ),
        ),
      'indices' =>
      array (
        0 =>
        array (
          'name' => 'accounts_contacts_1spk',
          'type' => 'primary',
          'fields' =>
          array (
            0 => 'id',
            ),
          ),
        1 =>
        array (
          'name' => 'accounts_contacts_1_ida1',
          'type' => 'index',
          'fields' =>
          array (
            0 => 'accounts_contacts_1accounts_ida',
            ),
          ),
        2 =>
        array (
          'name' => 'accounts_contacts_1_alt',
          'type' => 'alternate_key',
          'fields' =>
          array (
            0 => 'accounts_contacts_1contacts_idb',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ); 
3. In accounts_contacts_1.php file:

<?php
include('custom/metadata/accounts_contacts_1MetaData.php');
?>
```

I just wanted to create a field in relationship that's all . Maybe I am missing somewhere in manifest file or i needed to include some additional file.

Comment: What version of SugarCRM are you using? When you encounter the 500 error, are there any entries in your sugarcrm.log?

Comment: @Reisclef, Thanks, for the comment I am using SugarCRM EE 7.6.1. I didn't check sugar log out but I think it mostly says about permission issue. Is permission really matter for creating custom relationships through module loader.

Comment: @egg, please give a look of above code I know somewhere I am mistaking. So please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. You can follow following steps to create relationships in SugarCRM through module loader.

Step 1:- Give permission to your sugar directory according to following
 For Linux: http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Platform_Management/Required_File_System_Permissions_on_Linux/
For Windows:
http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Platform_Management/Required_File_System_Permissions_on_Windows_With_IIS/

Step 2:- In manifest.php

```
<?php
 $manifest = array(
    'acceptable_sugar_flavors' => array('CE','PRO','CORP','ENT','ULT'),
    'acceptable_sugar_versions' => array(
        'exact_matches' => array(),
        'regex_matches' => array('(.*?)\\.(.*?)\\.(.*?)$'),
        ),
    'author' => 'Ravi Ranjan',
    'description' => 'Relationship',
    'icon' => '',
    'is_uninstallable' => true,
    'name' => 'custom relation',
    'published_date' => '2017-08-10 2017 11:45:04',
    'type' => 'module',
    'version' => '20170810',
    );

 $installdefs = array(
    'id' => 'package_20170810',
    'copy' => array(
        0 => array(
            'from' => '<basepath>/accounts_contacts_1MetaData.php',
            'to' => 'custom/metadata/accounts_contacts_1MetaData.php',
            ),

        1 => array(
            'from' => '<basepath>/accounts_contacts_1.php',
            'to' => 'custom/Extension/application/Ext/TableDictionary/accounts_contacts_1.php',
            ),

        ),

    );

 ?>
```

Step 3:- The contents of both  file accounts_contacts_1MetaData.php and accounts_contacts_1.php will be same as you can see in question.

Step 4:- Compress all three files and upload through module loader, after installation quick repair and rebuild.

**Go in Studio > Accounts > Relationships You will see a new field there name accounts_contacts_1 That's what I wanted to create.**